# How to return value for different layers of (x,y) levels

Tags: python, logic

My problem is the following. I a functional requirement where the user can choose between 3 or 5 levels and a value will be returned according to which level (x,y) belong.

for example in 3 levels we have

```
def f(x,y):
        if (0 <= x <= 0.3 and 0 <= y <= 1) or (0.3 <= x <= 1 and 0 <= y <= 0.3):
            return 1
        elif (0.3 < x <= 0.6 and 0.3 < y <= 1) or (0.6 <= x <= 1 and 0.3 < y <= 0.6):
            return 2
        else:
            return 3
```

for 5 levels we would have 5 if branches and so on.

I was wondering which is the best way(or a good) to do that in Python with the DRY principle. My mind is short of short circuited right now.

Comment: can `x` or `y` on input ever be `> 1`?

Comment: Or less than 0 for that matter.

Comment: no, only [0, 1]. It is normalized way before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first, we can recognize that we can rewrite your program as:

```
def f(x, y):
    if min(x, y) <= 0.3:
        return 1
    elif min(x, y) <= 0.6:
        return 2
    else:
        return 3
```

We can then format this into a for loop fairly easily:

```
from __future__ import division

def f(x, y, n=3):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if min(x, y) <= i/n:
            return i
    else:
        return n
```

We could also write a math equation for this and drop the for loop:

```
def f(x, y, n=3):
    return int(min(x, y) * n) + 1
```

This last equation will fail when `x == 1` or `y == 1`. You should probably just either make a special case for that, or also perform a `max(result_so_far, n)` as well.

Comment: you mean as in a lambda expression? Thanks!

Comment: @MayTheSchwartzBeWithYou: I've edited the answer with my thoughts on the math variant.

Comment: The for loop is needed, because I don't actually return numbers but Qt brushes.